# Working of Regression in sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

How does scikit-learn's sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression class work with regression as well as classification problems?

As given on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) as well as a number of sources, since the output of Logistic Regression is based on the ***sigmoid function***, it returns a probability. Then how does the sklearn class work as both a classifier and regressor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logistic regression is a method for classification, not regression. This goes for scikit-learn as for anywhere else.

If you have entered continuous values as the target vector `y`, then `LogisticRegression` will most probably fail, as it interprets the unique values of `y`, i.e. `np.unique(y)` as different classes. So you may end up having as many classes as samples.

TL;DR: Logistic regression needs a categorical target variable, because it is a classification method.

Comment: thanks! i had myself expected it to fail but when it worked,  I got a bit confused.... thanks for clearing up my doubt anyways :)